# How to see which applications are saved on phone

Tags: applications, insufficient-memory

Recently I get a lot of warnings that the internal memory is full, which also led to full SMS memory.

What I did was to delete some messages, which seemed to work for a while.
Yesterday however, I installed some updates and those warnings messages came up again.

Is there a way to find out which application are installed on my phone?
A rather indirect way is to remove the SD card and see which applications are on.

Is there a way to figure this out in a direct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings option you have Application Manager. In Application Manager if you swipe to the left you will get apps installed on the sd card. It should look something like this:

[image: Application Manager Android]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I know how to find which apps are installed in the SD card, however I want to see which applications are installed on the phone.

Comment: Well, if the app is not on the SD Card it's on the phone.

Comment: But if there are a lot of applications installed both on the phone and the SD, you have to make a list of the ones on the card, which takes times and it's not so direct.

Comment: Then I suggest you use another app to manage those. Here's one that seems to be what you need: [AppMgr III (App 2 SD)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.